# My list only showing first two items in spinner

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

I am getting a list that contains two lists of Time zones, of US and Canada from server. Id of Canada list is 1 and Us is 2.That lists contains string id and some other strings. I need that string id to be listed in spinner so that's why I am making new list that contains only strings that I need.
I put id's of countries in a `switch` statement and it should put list in `spinner` and it works fine. But it shows only the first two items from list.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
                listCountryId.add(list.get(0).getTimeZoneModelList().get(i).getId());
```

so basically idea is that I loop through my list from server and because I always have only two lists in that list, in this case I loop through first list. That is why I hardcoded. When I debug I can see that my `getTimeZoneModelList()`  contains full list but when I debug `listCountryId()` it contains only first two items.

this is my full code:

```
private void setUpSpinner() {
        switch (model.getCountry().getCoutryId()) {
            case 1:

                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
                    listCountryId.add(list.get(0).getTimeZoneModelList().get(i).getId());
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapterMembers = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listCountryId);
                adapterMembers.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                binding.timezoneSpinner.setAdapter(adapterMembers);

                Log.i(TAG, "lista idjeva: " + Arrays.toString(listCountryId.toArray()));
                break;
            case 2:
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    listCountryId.add(list.get(1).getTimeZoneModelList().get(i).getId());
                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                        context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listCountryId);

                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                binding.timezoneSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                Log.i(TAG, "lista idjeva: " + Arrays.toString(listCountryId.toArray()));

                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping in the `list` which contains only 2 (US & Canda), but actually you need the underlying list of codes

So, In `case 1`: You need to change the list in the for loop from

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
```

To:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.get(0).getTimeZoneModelList().size(); i++)
```

And do the same for `case 2`

Answer (score 2):

It is happenning because your loop is indeed running two times. It should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.get(0).getTimeZoneModelList().size(); i++)
    listCountryId.add(list.get(0).getTimeZoneModelList().get(i).getId());
```

Even better:

```
List<TimeZoneModel> timeZoneModelList = listCountryId.add(list.get(0).getTimeZoneModelList();
for (int i = 0; i < timeZoneModelList.size(); i++)
        listCountryId.add(timeZoneModelList.get(i).getId());
```

The second way is more efficient.